# Uwp Combobox IsTextSearchEnabled doesnt work in a dialog

Tags: xaml, uwp, combobox, dialog, selectionchanged

So I want this behaviour that when the combobox is in focus and I press a letter on the keyboard it should automatically select the 1st item which starts with that pressed letter, I found out this behaviour was built into combobox with property "IsTextSearchEnabled" so it was working fine until I discovered that if a combobox is in a content dialog this property set to "true" doesnt work anymore.

```
 <ComboBox
            Header="States, with keyboard support"
            IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding States2}" />
```

Comment: I could reproduce your issue, I need do more testing to confirm this problem and report it, and you could also post this problem with windows feed back hub.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT yup I just submitted it to the feedback hub as well

Comment: Current there is workaround that use popup control to replace ContentDialog as the parent container.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT that might not be possible for us, bcz we r using custom styling on our content dialogs so it will be hard to replace that with popup, do we have any other workaround instead?

Comment: Or replace ComboBox with AutoSuggestBox and process text association manually